# subtotal and total for strings

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table named abc with 2 columns-city and houses.(I am using MYSQL 6.0)

```
 houses            city
    A               P
    B               Q
    C               P
    D               R
    E               P
    F               S
    G               S
```

I want the output in this way:

```
houses             city
A                   p                  
C                   p
E                   p
noofhouses:         3

B                   Q
noofhouses:         1 

D                   R
noofhouses:         1

F                   S
G                   S
noofhouses:         2
totalhouses         7
```

So basically i want a list of names of houses and no. of houses in a city.
is that possible??
please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516261/subtotals-and-sql

Comment: Are you want to report..??

Comment: Your confused - How is house A related to city A in your table?

Comment: oh I am sorry. I edited now.

Comment: @noise: its not same as subtotals and sql! this is a different case.

Answer (score 1):

If you did want to do this entirely in SQL, you could use:

```
SELECT IFNULL(Title, aHouse) AS House, IFNULL(Total, aCity) AS City
FROM
(
    SELECT House AS aHouse, City AS aCity, NULL AS Total, NULL AS Title
    FROM @abc 
    UNION 
    SELECT NULL AS aHouse, City AS aCity, CAST(COUNT(House)  AS CHAR(4)) AS Total, 'noofhouses:' AS Title
    FROM @abc
    GROUP BY City
    UNION 
    SELECT NULL AS aHouse, 'zzzzz' AS aCity, CAST(COUNT(House)  AS CHAR(4)) AS Total, 'total:' AS Title
    FROM @abc
) a
ORDER BY aCity, Title, aHouse
```

Output:

```
House       City
----------- ----
A           P   
C           P   
E           P   
noofhouses: 3   
B           Q   
noofhouses: 1   
D           R   
noofhouses: 1   
F           S   
G           S   
noofhouses: 2   
total:      7
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ffdb8/2/0)

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

```
select
group_concat(houses), count(*), city
from
Table1
group by city;
```

or

```
select a.houses, a.city, noofhouses
from Table1 a
inner join (
select
count(*) as noofhouses, city
from Table1
group by city
) b on a.city = b.city
order by a.city, noofhouses desc, a.houses;
```

- see them working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee7c4/5/1)

It's not exactly as your output, but the information in it is the same. Databases are not there to format the data nicely. This should be done in application layer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `WITH ROLLUP` option to create subtotals automatically. Put that in a subquery, and use the outer query to reformat the result.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN city IS NULL THEN 'totalhouses'
            WHEN houses IS NULL THEN 'noofhouses'
            ELSE houses
       END houses,
       CASE WHEN houses IS NULL then num
            ELSE city
       END city
FROM (
    SELECT houses, city, count(*) num
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY city, houses WITH ROLLUP) x
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86489/6)

Comment: hey thank you for the solution. But at the city column I am getting 'blob' as the entries. any idea why and how i can solve this? I just copy-pasted it in MySQL 6.0 and i got 'blob' in every entry of the City column..Please help.

Comment: MySQL 5.x doesn't have a problem with it, but the newer version may not like that some rows have a number and others have a string. Try changing `then num` to `then cast(num as char)`.