# get summarize sum each group by and order by element using mysql

Tags: mysql

i have table as following

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | name  | price |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | test  |   500 |
|  2 | test  |   400 |
|  3 | test  |   600 |
|  4 | saman |   300 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

i want to get  result like following,a try to get using group by withing from statement but it give only one result,

```
+----+-------+-------+
| id | name  | price |
+----+-------+-------+
|  1 | test  |   500 |
|  2 | test  |   400 |
|  3 | test  |   600
|    |       |
|    |       |       |
|    |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+
|  sub total |1500   |
+----+-------+-------+
|    |       |
|  4 | saman |   300 |
|    |       |       |
+----+-------+-------+
|  sub total | 300   |

+----+-------+-------+
| total        1800  |
+----+-------+-------+
```

but i haven't  any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [`WITH ROLLUP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) modifier:

```
SELECT id, name, SUM(price) AS price
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY name, id WITH ROLLUP
```

The subtotals by name will have `id = NULL`, the grand total will have both `id = NULL` and `name = NULL`.

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bdc72/4)

If you want the query to display the `subtotal` and `total` labels, you can make this a subquery, and have the outer query test the columns to replace them with `subtotal` and `total`. See [subtotal and total for strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925496/subtotal-and-total-for-strings/19926036#19926036) for an example of this.

Comment: its ok only total how i get sum of each duplicate colums i want to also get three  sum of test value as example

Comment: Isn't that in my demo? It's the row with `id = NULL` and `name = test`