# Add rows in a table after check it with another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I've this table "Mileage" with the following data

```
user   DateMil        Dist
 10   2014-09-04      102
 10   2014-09-07      250
 15   2014-09-04      180
 15   2014-09-06      135
```

and another table "Initialization" with the following data

```
user   DateInit         Init
 10   2014-09-03      12500
 15   2014-09-03      20000
```

How i need is get the last of data of table "Initialization" and join it with table of "Mileage" with the same user and add a new rows in the table of "Initialization".The resultant table should be as below

```
user   DateInit         Init
 10   2014-09-03      12500
 10   2014-09-04      12602(12500+102=last(init)+Dist)
 10   2014-09-07      12852(12602+250)
 15   2014-09-03      20000
 15   2014-09-04      20180(2000+180)
 15   2014-09-06      20315(20180+135)
```

Comment: Did you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4516261/subtotals-and-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `CTE` to put together a `UNION` of the two original tables. Then,
if you are using SQL SERVER 2012+, you can use `SUM` to calculate running totals:

```
 ;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT [user], DateMil AS DateInit, Dist AS Init
    FROM Mileage

    UNION

    SELECT [user], DateInit, Init 
    FROM Initialization
)
SELECT [user],  DateInit, 
       SUM(Init) OVER (PARTITION BY [user] ORDER BY DateInit) As Init
FROM CTE
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0f59e/1)